# Vuex 'splice' and 'set' mutations extremely slow on large lists/dicts

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

I have a Nuxt 2 application with a the following `vuex` (v3) state and simple mutation:

```js
state: {
  bulletsList: [],
  bulletsDict: {}, 
  // ...
}
```

```js
mutations: {
  createBullet(state, data) {
    // Compute index based on some criteria...
    idx = ...

    // Non-state test
    // Only to check sanity, not in actual code...
    dictCopy = structuredClone(state.bulletsDict)
    console.time('test')
    Vue.set(dictCopy, data.id, data)
    console.timeEnd('test')
    // END test

    // Update list
    console.time('splice')
    state.bulletsList.splice(idx, 0, data)
    console.timeEnd('splice')

    // Update dict
    console.time('set')
    Vue.set(state.bulletsDict, data.id, data)
    console.timeEnd('set')
  },
  // ...
}
```

As long as the list and dict are small everything is fine, but once they get larger (currently ~6000 entries each) the mutations get extremely slow, ~50-100ms each (MacBook Pro 2018) for `splice` and `set`.

The test on a copy of the dict, which is not part of the state is very fast ~0.01ms.

Is that a problem of `vue` / `vuex` reactivity, or my code somehow, and is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: So, you want to mutate the state of each 6k elements on the client side? Or only one element out of the 6k?

Comment: Only one element, aka. I want to add one item to both the list and the dict.

Comment: Do you add it in the middle or at the start/beginning? Maybe Vue2's approach wasn't great on that part. Worth a try with Vue3's proxies. Even tho, it may also just be an algorithm issue? Do you use the state on the page you're editing that one out? Try that on a page where you don't have any components using that one, maybe their rendering is taking time (Vue devtools giving you that info).

Comment: Just tested calling the mutation from a blank page and it makes no difference, still ~50-100ms for both splice and set.

Comment: @kissu I resolved it, see my own answer below. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that strict mode was turned on in my `vuex` setup, which added ~50-100ms to the splice and set operations. With `strict = false` both operations take less than 1ms.

More details on that here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

Comment: This mode is quite interesting because it will double-check that you are mutating the state properly. I recommend leaving that one on because it will avoid you quite some issues down the road. It's disabled on production anyway!